# Get top continued dates with out any breaks in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
emp code date
TTE0149 2020-01-01
TTE0149 2020-01-02
TTE0149 2020-01-03
TTE0149 2020-01-04
TTE0149 2020-01-05
TTE0149 2020-01-07
TTE0149 2020-01-09
TTE0149 2020-01-10
TTE0149 2020-01-11
TTE0149 2020-01-12
```

I need Like

```
emp code date
TTE0149 2020-01-01
TTE0149 2020-01-02
TTE0149 2020-01-03
TTE0149 2020-01-04
TTE0149 2020-01-05
```

or

```
TTE0149 5{1,2,3,4,5}
```

after 5th date there is a break.

Comment: Your question is not very readable, please try to format and explain question, providing code or SQL samples that you tried. That would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Hope You understand now

Comment: Are you asking for an SQL ? Like: `select empcode, date from table where date < '2020-01-06'`

Comment: No for mysql, i want query like without mentioned date(2020-01-06) .Bcas anothe employee may work til 2020-01-10..

Comment: As it stands, this is too broad.

Comment: Why not 10, 11, 12?

Comment: I want first continues date only @TheImpaler